# How do I link structs? Need to optimise performance

Tags: arrays, swift, database, struct

I am trying to optimise my code to minimise the download size of unnecessary information.

**My objective is to link items in the testData array to call methods from another struct.**

Here is an example:

```
struct Recipe: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var imageName: String
}
let testData = [
    Recipe(title: "Recipe1", description: "Description1", imageName: "Image1"
    Recipe(title: "Recipe2", description: "Description2", imageName: "Image2"
    Recipe(title: "Recipe3", description: "Description3", imageName: "Image3"
]

// Then another struct, which needs to be linked to members of the array above
// Code below is incorrect, will not work
struct CommentSection {
    var recipe: Recipe // would I link a variable to struct here or how else to proceed?
    var user: String
    var body: String
}
let commentData [
    CommentSection(user: "User1", body: "body1"
    CommentSection(user: "User1", body: "body1"
]
```

**What I would like to do is to be able to associate items within CommentSection with items in the testData array without making a substruct.**

I know that classes can inherit, although have much of the app tied in the the struct I.E database, arrays, etc. therefore would like to keep it a struct.

**How would I proceed to call CommentSection.user & body which should be linked to [#] of testData without accessing it through the Recipe struct?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do.
But, first of all:
a comment should be linked to the object being commented -
it should look like this:

```
struct CommentedObject {
    ...
}

struct Comment {
    ...
    let ownerId, commentedObjectId: String
    ...
}
```

where:
**ownerId** - commentator id,
**commentedObjectId** - id of the commented object,

Second:

> `@DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString`

should look like this -
@DocumentID var id: String? –
Firebase automatically creates an ID when an object is initialized,
don't forget about a **CodingKeys** enum.